# sql-lint without configuration file

Tags: sql, lint

How can I run sql-lint without configuration file?
If I do not have configuration file when running sql-lint, I get:

FAIL: following sql-lint errors found:
Can't open file /home/tavni/.config/sql-lint/config.json. Does it exist?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Author here. That message does not stop the checks from running it's just a recommendation that you **should** create a config file because you'll have a better experience.

Some recent work has been done to make this more obvious and is going to be in the next release. Hope that helps!